# Call c++ class library from Delphi

Tags: c++, delphi, dll

Is it possible to call C++ class library from delphi 2007? What is the way of doing that? I know how to call dll function, but how to deal with class?

Comment: FWIW, since there is no standard as to how classes have to be layed out in memory, there can easily be differences between how the same source code is, after compilation, layed out in memory. So it is generally not even possible to access an exposed C++ class with code from another compiler, or even from the same brand compiler but a different version. Exposing classes directly is something one should not do from a DLL, unless it is for private use only.

Answer (score 8):

There are several ways to do this, but you can't use a C++ class directly. Both useful ways to achieve this require some work and are extensively described here:

#### Using C++ objects in Delphi (http://rvelthuis.de/articles/articles-cppobjs.html)

### Update

OK, I was asked to do an update. The article describes two ways:

- Writing and exposing C functions that take the C++ object as (first) parameter (the C++ type is simply passed on as opaque type in Delphi), which simply perform the functionality the class provides by calling the class methods with the right parameters. The C functions can be called from Delphi.
- Writing a COM wrapper for the class. The article describes how this can be done in C++.

Details can be found in the article.

Comment: We generally prefer answers to include at least some detail. Your's is simply a link to an offsite page. You should at least summarise the content of this offsite link. As described here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94022/how-can-i-link-to-an-external-resource-in-a-community-friendly-way

Comment: FWIW, in what way is that different from, say, linking to another SO question that provides an answer, or to, say, the offsite article that is often quoted that describes all the problems with floating point?

Comment: @vico: it would be nice if you accepted one of the answers here.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot consume C++ classes from Delphi. You will need to wrap them in some other interop friendly manner. For instance:

1. Wrap the C++ classes with C style functions that expose the functionality.
2. Expose COM objects that provide the functionality.